# How do you substantiate article "a" after the plural verb "are" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, articles

There are a confirmed 16 trees in the world that produce 40 types of fruit each year.

Comment: Where does this sentence comes from?

Comment: Knowledgenuts.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are **a confirmed 16** trees in the world...

This construction is common in reportage contexts.

What is being confirmed is the quantity, here 16.  That factuality is not plural, hence **a**.

A quantity *qua* Quantity is singular: *How many **is** that again?*  ***Is*** 16 rather few?

**a confirmed** modifies the quantity **16**.   **are** and **trees** agree in number.

We can have confirmed quantities and unconfirmed quantities.

When a number is not absolutely confirmed, we would hedge with something like this:

> There are **some 16** trees in the world that...

or we can say

> **An unconfirmed 16** people  were injured when the bus and truck collided.